# Jquery Mobile align text box

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have the following listview with text boxes. I wanted to get the same feel as the ipad.
How do I align the text boxes so are right below one another. Currently it looks mismatched.

```
      <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" style="width:30%;">
  <li data-role="fieldcontain">
  <label for="name">First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" value=""    />            
  </li>

        <li data-role="fieldcontain">
  <label for="name">MI:</label>
        <input type="text" name="mi" id="mi" value="" style="width:5%;"  />                
  </li>
      </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know why you needed to set style for ul and input tags. 
But I have put together a fiddle with different styling you can achieve.
http://jsfiddle.net/nachiket/nnRPv/
Does any one of it helps?